# Routing custom action in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a very simple question.
Trying to figure out what is the simplest way to route the custom action in rails 3.

Let's say i have controller `UsersController` and action `promote_to_premium`

Nor

```
http://localhost:3000/users/#{user_id}/promote_to_premium
```

neither

```
http://localhost:3000/users/promote_to_premium/#{user_id}
```

works.

Should I specify in routes.rb every custom action that differs from new/delete/update/create/ect/....?????

Thank You.

Comment: The second, non accepted, answer actually answers the question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you need to specify in your routes.rb.
Example:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    post :promote_to_premium
  end
end
```

This way you can access the route like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/#{user_id}/promote_to_premium
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this in routes.rb:

```
match "/users/:id/promote_to_premium" => "users#promote_to_premium"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should mention the route in routes.rb file for custom methods in the controller.

You can specify the routes using either `get""` or a `match""=>""` or a `"post"`
when you write get `"controller/something"` something should be an action(method) called by the name "something" in your controller. But in your case you cannot use `get"controller/:id"` as there is no `":id"` method in your controller. So, you should `match` your `controller/:id` to some `'action'` in your controller. 
Hence you need to write

```
"match users/:id/promote_to_premium"=>  "users#promote_to_premium"
```

But if you are writing something into the database then you should use '`post`'. From whatever i know, i think you can try

```
match 'users/:id/promote_to_premium' => 'users#promote_to_premium', :via => :post
```

You can study more about routes in the below link:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to specify every route. Actually you define the normal routes too with the `resource` command.

There is a specific wildcard command to allow access of any action, but it is only for debug purposes, because it allows access to actions you may not want to be accessible:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Comment: Why only for debug? If I'm right that was working this way in Rails 1.3

Comment: It is unsafe, to let the user address any action just like that. What if you have an action which requires multiple parameter, or something like that and anyone can access it just by typing the controller/actiona as an url?

Comment: @matzi: well, the controller should verify that it gets correct data anyways.

Comment: It should of course, but better not leave anything open by default, just think about some helper function accidentaly mistaken for a valid action.